# get bean definitions without starting context

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

I am writing a `ContextLoader` that takes additional context files to replace into the existing context. What I am doing is taking the locations and passing them into a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. Then I am getting the `BeanFactory` from the context from which I am getting the `BeanDefinitions`. I am then registering these `BeanDefinitions` in another (the main) context.

Then issue is that I would like to get the `BeanDefinitions` from the context without actually staring the context / constructing the beans. Is this possible?

Again, I have a main context A and a temp context B. I am taking all the `BeanDefinitions` from B and registering them in A. Then I close and dispose of B. The beans are then create / destroyed as context A is started / restarted. However, I noticed that the beans are also created / destroyed once during the process of creating B and getting the definitions. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are doing this instead of relying on standart way of combining ApplicationContexts, i.e. in case of XML <import resource="classpath:...." /> ?

Comment: In a test env, I want to separately specify replacement beans (like Springockito) without dependence on order (which is a feature of Spring that is not guaranteed to always be supported)